# Codiad Permission Denied Error

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, ide

I recently installed the Codiad IDE and followed the instructions on their readme, I have also assigned the www-data group to run the /var/www/web folder where codiad is installed, the correct file permissions have been given to all the folders but I get this error when I try to save a file

```
Nov  1 19:27:57 MultiCrew apache2: PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/test/index.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/web/components/filemanager/class.filemanager.php on line 453
Nov  1 19:27:57 MultiCrew apache2: PHP Stack trace:
Nov  1 19:27:57 MultiCrew apache2: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/web/components/filemanager/controller.php:0
Nov  1 19:27:57 MultiCrew apache2: PHP   2. Filemanager->modify() /var/www/web/components/filemanager/controller.php:82
Nov  1 19:27:57 MultiCrew apache2: PHP   3. fopen() /var/www/web/components/filemanager/class.filemanager.php:453
```

I have also tried giving the /components /filemanager and /class.filemanager.php folders/files the 777 permission but that didnt fix it.

Here are the results of the ls -alh /var /var/www and /var/www/web commands

```
root@MultiCrew:~# ls -alh /var
total 60K
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root   4.0K Aug 14 20:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root   4.0K Oct  4 18:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4.0K Nov  1 06:25 backups
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root   4.0K Feb  9  2017 cache
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4.0K Oct 13 06:25 crash
drwxr-xr-x 64 root root   4.0K Oct 28 12:31 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4.0K Apr 12  2016 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Aug  2  2016 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 11 root syslog 4.0K Nov  1 06:25 log
drwxrwsrwt  2 root mail   4.0K Oct 28 12:29 mail
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4.0K Dec 18  2016 opt
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4.0K Aug 14 20:44 repo
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Aug  2  2016 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4.0K Jun 29  2016 snap
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4.0K Oct 28 12:31 spool
drwxrwxrwt  5 root root   4.0K Nov  1 19:39 tmp
drwxrwxrwx 12 git  root   4.0K Oct 27 20:11 www
root@MultiCrew:~# ls -alh /var/www
total 30M
drwxrwxrwx 12 git      root     4.0K Oct 27 20:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4.0K Aug 14 20:43 ..
-rw-------  1 sso      sso      6.5K Oct 31 18:08 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root     4.0K Sep 16 11:05 book
drwx------  2 sso      sso      4.0K Aug 23 21:13 .cache
drwxrwxrwx  7 sso      www-data 4.0K Oct 15 14:36 fly
drwxr-xr-x 16 sso      www-data 4.0K Sep 14 19:27 forums
drwxr-xr-x  9 git      www-data 4.0K Oct  4 20:20 html
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      30M Sep 15 09:18 multicrew.zip
-rw-------  1 sso      sso        68 Sep 15 08:41 .mysql_history
drwxrwxr-x  2 sso      sso      4.0K Aug 29 03:48 .nano
drwxr-xr-x  4 sso      root     4.0K Sep  1 04:02 portal
-rw-------  1 root     root     1.0K Aug 27 06:52 .rnd
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4.0K Oct 29 11:14 status
-rw-r--r--  1 sso      sso         0 Aug 26 19:53 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  6 git      root     4.0K Oct  1 12:06 test
drwxrwxrwx 11 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 web
root@MultiCrew:~# ls -alh /var/www/web
total 152K
drwxrwxrwx 11 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 .
drwxrwxrwx 12 git      root     4.0K Oct 27 20:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  413 Oct 27 20:12 AUTHORS.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  456 Oct 27 20:12 build.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  12K Oct 27 20:12 common.php
drwxrwxrwx 17 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 components
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1.2K Oct 27 20:12 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1.8K Oct 27 20:12 config.example.php
-rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data www-data 1.6K Oct 28 09:15 config.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 1.8K Oct 27 20:12 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 28 09:16 data
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  567 Oct 27 20:12 .editorconfig
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 1.2K Oct 27 20:12 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  173 Oct 27 20:12 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  19K Oct 27 20:12 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  634 Oct 27 20:12 INSTALL.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 js
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 languages
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 lib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 1.2K Oct 27 20:12 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 plugins
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  907 Oct 27 20:12 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data  24K Oct 27 20:12 style_guide.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 27 20:12 themes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1.4K Oct 27 20:12 .travis.yml
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Oct 28 09:20 workspace
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure **ALL the folders in the path** have access for the user trying to access those files.

Comment: The chown command I ran was to the directory /var/www/web so surely that should cover everything inside the web directory?

Comment: I just ran sudo chown :www-data /var/www/web, sudo chown :www-data /var/www/web/components, sudo chown :www-data /var/www/web/components/filemanager and sudo chown :www-data /var/www/web/components/filemanager/class.filemanager.php but it still doesnt work

Comment: chown is to change owner, chmod changes permissions. chown -r and chmod -r are recursive, without the -r they only apply to the folder you specified.

Comment: I just ran chown -r :www-data /var/www/web and chown :www-data -r /var/www/web just to be sure but it still doesnt work

Comment: add the result of `ls -alh` to `/var/`, `/var/www/` and `/var/www/web/` to your question, please. Also, which user is running the apache2 server?

Comment: Edited my question, and the www-data user runs apache

Comment: Still cant seem to figure this out, any ideas @Alfabravo